# How to replace a character only when found within a specific words within a csv file

Tags: regex, xml, pentaho, kettle, pdi

Problem description:
Parse a csv file (with a pipe character as a delimiter) with pipe in one of the data fields. This data field will always be in an XML tags i.e.,  (starting tag) and  (closing tag). So, I am looking to parse the csv file with some kind of exclusion logic to ignore delimiters if found within the tags.

My goal is to parse this data corrected pipe delimited file (as shown below in the Expected result)  using Pentaho Data Integration tool to load into our database. After the data correction it is plain and simple to read the csv file.

Sample data:

```
abc| <evar29> d|e|f</evar29> | ghijk
xxx| yyyy| <evar29>z|z</evar29>
```

Expected Result ("|" replaced within evar29 tags with a "@@"):

```
 abc| <evar29> d @@ e @@ f</evar29> | ghijk
xxx| yyyy| <evar29>z @@ z</evar29>
```

Comment: @PhilipBrack Below is what I have tried. I am still trying to figure out how to accomplish the same with multiple occurences of the pipe character.

Answer (score 1):

For your case: `(?<=<evar29>.*)(?=.*</evar29>)\|`

For general: `(?<=<.+?>.*)(?=.*<.+?>)\|`

Comment: If I understood this right, lookbehind wont work for my question as I want the regex engine to replace the pipe with a "@". Lookbehinds won't consume any characters.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here after reading about sed and awk. However, this doesn't seem to be working well for multiple occurrences of the pipe character within those tags. I am currently working on that. Appreciate any help.

Command:  `sed -n 's/<evar29>\(.*\)|\(.*\)<\/evar29>/<evar29>\1@@\2<\/evar29>/pg' test.txt`
Description: Substitute the pipe character that occurs in between the evar29 tags.
The string right after the evar29 starting tag is broken down and captured using capture groups and then concatenated later using the desired character (in my case @@).

Command to replace the character and write to a file is below:

```
sed -i 's/<evar29>\(.*\)|\(.*\)<\/evar29>/<evar29>\1@@\2<\/evar29>/g' test.txt
```

Hope this helps anyone looking for a solution of this kind.